# access iframe name from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I though this would be simple enough but I can't find the answer. I need to know how I can access an iframe's name from within said iframe. I was trying something like this but it's not working.

```
<iframe name="thename">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(parent.name);
  </script>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You were nearly right. Setting the `name` attribute on a `frame` or `iframe` sets the `name` property of the frame's global `window` object to that string. (Not `parent`, which refers to the window of the document that owns the frame.)

So unless some other script has deliberately changed the name, it's as simple as:

```
1.html:
<iframe name="tim" href="2.html"></iframe>

2.html:
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(window.name); // tim
</script>
```

Comment: how about accessing attributes of the iframe? for example if it has some data-set attr?

Comment: @AlexStack: `window.frameElement` gets you the element from the parent document that refers to yourself, you can then `getAttribute` on it (assuming you have SOP access). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097870/jquery-access-iframe-id-from-iframe-content/4098384#4098384 for fallback where not available

Comment: This will not work cross-origin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement

Answer (score 65):

There is a combination of answers I prefer:

```
// window.frameElement Gets IFrame element which document inside
window.frameElement.getAttribute("Name");
```

It works on IE7+, Mozilla & Chrome

Comment: I like this answer more than the accepted answer because it references the actual iframe element.

Comment: this not work on http://publisherconsole.appspot.com/safeframe/creative-preview.html, any suggestions?

Comment: MDN documentation: [`Window.frameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement)

Answer (score 9):

in some cases `window.frameElement` returns `null` in iframe, so i figured workaround for it.

**1. you need to set hash in src url of iframe**

```
<iframe name="tim" href="2.html#your-hash"></iframe>
```

**2. in iframe you can get this hash with**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hash = window.location.hash;
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, an IFRAME element shouldn't contain anything, it's targeting another document. So using a SCRIPT tag inside an IFRAME doesn't make alot of sense. Instead, use the SCRIPT inside the called document, e.g.

iframe_caller.html:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe id="theIframe" name="theIframe" src="iframe_doc.html"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

iframe_doc.html:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var iframes= parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    document.write(iframes[0].getAttribute("id"));
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note I'm using `parent.document.function()` there.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
parent.document.getElementById('idhere').name;
```

You have to use the parent and then get the element either byId, Name, etc... then access the name property.

So your code should be like:

```
<iframe name="thename">
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var iframeName = parent.document.getElementById('idhere').name;
 </script>
</iframe>
```

Comment: What if you don't know the ID or the iframe sits on a separate domain?

Comment: You would then have to use getElementsByTagName and iterate over the results by some criteria.