# Chrome - find iframe by frameId(not id attribute)

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that can find a request comes from which iframe. Now I can get a frameId by listen to [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) so I can get frameId(see the frameId section in the link, not the id attribute in iframe tag).

Can I use this frameId to find the iframe? What I want is only retrieve the iframe tag's attribute like name, width and height.

Thanks

Here is my working code base on [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan)'s answer below.

```
//frameScript.js
(function() {

    var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    var width = Math.max( body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth,
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth );

    return {
        width: width,
        height: height
    }
}());

//background.js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(currentTabId, {
                    allFrames: true,
                    file: 'frameScript.js'
                }, function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

Comment: please update the question with some sample code so we can add suggestions to your approach

Comment: Thanks! I will be aware of it next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the frame ID to inject a content script into the exact frame (you'll need host permissions, but then again you already have them for webRequest).

From there, you can get width and height as well as [name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248951/access-iframe-name-from-inside-iframe). It just so happens that those particular properties can be accessed from within the frame itself - it's not a general solution to get the `<iframe>` element itself.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  tabId,
  {frameId: frameId, file: "content.js"},
  function(data) { console.log(data[0]); }
);

// content.js

// Evaluate something to return it
{
  name: window.name,
  height: window.innerHeight
  width: window.innerWidth
};
```

Comment: @icl7126 those properties are only returned because the original question asked for them. Nothing is claimed about them being identifiers universally.