# Trigger close event of child iframe from within iframe, but without storing/passing iframe element ID?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

There are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754935/how-to-close-an-iframe-within-iframe-itself) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248951/access-iframe-name-from-inside-iframe), but none are identical.

Assume window A and child iframe B, both on the same domain.

How can you access the iframe element from within the child iframe itself?

The ultimate goal is to close the child iframe (B) without passing/storing ID/name information about the iframe. Ideally, there is a callback from the child iframe to the parent window, and this callback function contains a reference to the child iframe. The parent then calls `remove` on this reference.

No need to pass/store ID information related to the child iframe.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.frameElement` gets you access to the `iframe` element.